# ¿Cómo reiniciar los eventos de Jquery, para evitar la repetición de carga cada uno de ellos?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una página index que contiene los siguientes eventos.

```
<div id=”sub_page”></div>
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("a.menu_navegacion_abrircaja").on('click', function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var href = “nombrecontrollerEJ/view_ej;
            $.post(href, function (data) {
                        $("#sub_page").html(data);
                    });
        });
    });
```

En ella, al hacer click  cargo los contenidos html de subpáginas en el div sub_page. 
En la vista vista view_ej, traigo código html y además, código jquery. El código de Jquery de la vista que se añade al div del index es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#modal_establecer_turnos').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        alert(“hello”);
    });
});
```

Al dar click al link que contiene la clase “menu_navegacion_abrircaja”, me aparece el alert(“HOLA”);
Pero resulta que hay un problema, por cada vez que hago click al link, se me repite los mensajes de alertas (alert(“HOLA”);). Por ejemplo, la primera vez que le doy click al link que contiene la clase menu_navegacion_abrircaja, funciona bien mostrando una vez el alert, pero después le hago otra vez click al mismo link me muestra dos veces el alert, después lo hago por tercera vez, me muestra tres veces el alert, y así sucesivamente.

Me gustaría saber como poder resolver este problema.
¿Existirá alguna forma de reiniciar los eventos o handler del jquery, como los son los eventos click,change, “hidden.bs.modal”,etc., de tal manera que se evite su repetición de los eventos?

He visto los métodos unbind(), bind(), off(), que quizás podrían ser la solución, pero si fuera así, ¿como podría aplicarlos?

Answer (score 1):

Intenta agregar el comando `.off()` de jQuery asi:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#modal_establecer_turnos').off('hidden.bs.modal');
    $('#modal_establecer_turnos').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        alert(“hello”);
    });
});
```

Comment: podrias usar el evento off()  de la api de jquery